# Get description item from XML with PHP and ignore br tags

Tags: php, xml, dom, simplexml

I have this XML file:

```
http://www.dailymotion.com/rss/tag/house
```

I need obtain first title and description items content. Than I use this code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.dailymotion.com/rss/tag/house/', 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
echo $xml->channel->item->title . "<br>";
@$dom->loadHtml($xml->channel->item->description);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
echo $description = $xpath->evaluate("string(//p[1]/text())");
```

This is OUTPUT

```
Fabio Lenzi - Beautiful Sorrow (Ivan Scratchin Funky Mix)
Download:
```

But if I read xml, in description item I find this content within p tag:

```
<p>Download:<br>https://itunes.apple.com/it/album/beautiful-sorrow/id661901853<br><br>©
Copyright protected work. ℗ Frutilla Records - All rights reserved. Only for watching, 
listening and streaming. Downloading, copying, sharing and making available is strictly     
prohibited.<br>
<br>frutillarecords@gmail.com<br>alex.voghi@dancetool.net<br>info@dancetool.net - 
YourDancefloorTV – (Re)Discover your Dance greatest hits - YourDancefloorTV is your 
channel for all the best Dance music. Find your favorite tracks and artists and 
experience the best of Dance music. Subscribe for free to stay connected to our channel 
and easily access our video updates! - YourDancefloorTV: 
http://www.dailymotion.com/yourdancefloortv</p>
```

Than I noticed that parsing is interrupted from < br > tags. How can I ignore br tags and others any tags included in paragraph?
Any helps its really appreciated.

Comment: You could simply use `strip_tags()` on the content of the description item and then rewrap the result in `<p></p>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strip_tags` to remove html tags !

Example:

```
$stripped_string = strip_tags($unstripped_string, $allowable_tags);
```

Comment: no because if I use strip_tags, I remove p tag too. I need only remove tags within p paragraph.

Comment: @VincenzoLoPalo The second parameter to [strip_tags](http://us2.php.net/strip_tags) is a list of allowable tags.

Comment: @VincenzoLoPalo: Exactly!

Answer (score 0):

This may be ,

```
$x = // Your Result;

echo strip_tags($x,'<p>');
```